# Which transports does socket.io use on which browsers?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, long-polling, flashsocket

[Socket.io states that it selects the most capable transport](http://socket.io/#browser-support) based on which browser you are using and that it select from WebSocket, Adobe® Flash® Socket, AJAX long polling, AJAX multipart streaming, Forever Iframe, JSONP Polling. Is there a matrix breakdown somewhere that shows which transport it selects for each browser? Or maybe a place in the source code that shows this?